# Adding Google Maps to app as another activity

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-activity, android-maps-v2

I have problem. I am trying  add to my app Google Map as a new activity. I have changed a lot of times  my code, but still when I want to turn on activity which contain Google Map, my app is shutting down.

I am using Android Studio and I am testing my app on Huwei Ascand.

Maybe somebody will have some idea.

Logcat (in moment when I trying turn on activity with Google Maps):

```
12-28 01:19:30.894  28452-28452/com.example.user.elderly2 W/dalvikvm﹕ Refusing to reopen boot DEX '/system/framework/hwframework.jar'    
12-28 01:19:31.014  28452-28452/com.example.user.elderly2 I/Google Maps Android API﹕ Google Play services client version: 6587000
12-28 01:19:31.024  28452-28452/com.example.user.elderly2 I/Google Maps Android API﹕ Google Play services package version: 6599034
12-28 01:19:31.234  28452-28455/com.example.user.elderly2 E/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 2505K, 24% free 10764K/14019K, paused 12ms+3ms, total 53ms
12-28 01:19:31.284  28452-28455/com.example.user.elderly2 E/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 810K, 20% free 11341K/14019K, paused 12ms+2ms, total 37ms
12-28 01:19:31.474  28452-28455/com.example.user.elderly2 E/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 800K, 16% free 11822K/14019K, paused 12ms+14ms, total 77ms
12-28 01:19:31.675  28452-28455/com.example.user.elderly2 E/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 400K, 12% free 12434K/14019K, paused 12ms+13ms, total 72ms
12-28 01:19:31.685  28452-28452/com.example.user.elderly2 W/System.err﹕ Invalid int: ""
12-28 01:19:31.815  28452-28455/com.example.user.elderly2 E/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 576K, 10% free 12940K/14279K, paused 2ms+14ms, total 51ms
12-28 01:19:31.935  28452-28455/com.example.user.elderly2 E/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 684K, 10% free 12982K/14407K, paused 2ms+2ms, total 48ms
12-28 01:19:31.995  28452-28452/com.example.user.elderly2 W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40d2b438)
```

Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.user.elderly2" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<!--
 The following two permissions are not required to use
 Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended.
-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<!-- Maps API needs OpenGL ES 2.0. -->
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>
<!-- End of copy. -->


       <application

        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 



//Main Activity    
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

//Second activity from which I want to turn Google Maps    
        <activity
            android:name=".Main_Menu_Activity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main__menu_" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.user.elderly2.Main_Menu_Activity" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

// activity with Google Maps    
        <activity
            android:name=".Maps_Activity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps_" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.user.elderly2.Maps_Activity" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.default.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

           <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
               android:value="AIzaS************************TcfaQc"/>
           <meta-data
               android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
               android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />


    </application>

</manifest>
```

activity_maps.XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <fragment
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Maps_activity.java:

```
package com.example.user.elderly2;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.*;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.*;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import org.apache.http.HttpMessage;

public  class Maps_Activity extends FragmentActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps_);

        GoogleMap mMap;
        SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment)  getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mMap = fm.getMap();


    }


    }
```

Problem solved!. Explenation in comments!

Comment: Try replacing `class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"` by `android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"` in `activity_maps.xml`, see if that makes a difference. See e.g. [this documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Adding).

Comment: Thanks for engagement, but after modification is still the same situation. ;(

Comment: Also, `setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps_);` looks like it has an extra underscore that it shouldn't.

Comment: hymm.. I don"t now what You mean writting "stack trace". This is logcat from start to crash?

Comment: Can you show the section of your gradle build file where you set the play services version?

Comment: Of courese - http://pastie.org/pastes/9801373. Thanks very much for helping me ;)

Comment: Did you check that the underscore is just a typo? Otherwise, I don't have any more ideas.

Comment: Name of my layout file is     activity_maps_.xml     , what you can see on  this screen http://imgur.com/IOl2KK2. This is ok ?

Comment: Yes, that looks ok, you just have a typo in the question...

Comment: Maybe this will show something - 1. MainActivity.java (http://pastie.org/9801394) - 2. Main_Menu_Activity, from this screen I trying to turn on Maps_Activity (http://pastie.org/9801396).

Comment: Maybe error is causing by fact that activity "Maps_Activity" contains fragment and showing this activity demands other solution than normal Intent. Sth like "StartFragmentActivity" ?

Comment: Problem solved ! ;) I have to put  this line of code in manifest file `<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />` between `<application>....</aplication>`

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this issue by updating the code in following ways:

- Add the Map Receive permission in your manifest file.

  ```
  <uses-permission android:name="package_name.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
  ```
- In your Maps_activity.java class please change "R.layout.activity_maps_" with "R.layout.activity_maps"
- In the application tag of your manifest file

  ```
   <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
  ```

Hope this would help!!